# how to append a byte array to file without overwriting it using java

Tags: java, arrays, file, encryption, append

I trying to make an AES encryption and i am generating a salt . However i had encountered some issue. the below code work fine but whenever i encrypted the second and so on files, the salt in side the file is overwritten. any suggestion on how to append the salt byte [] into the salt fil without overwriting it ?

Guys..i updated my code..thanks for that portion  although it fixed the overwritting issue, it does not make it to next line.

output on my file : ˜V"Ã·Ò²Ö4ô¦ŒT‰mÊî0‘Z^'û•šÙK· = this is two salt combined.

any idea how to make it append on next line?

i trying saltoutfile.write("/n") but doesnt work

```
    public byte[] generateSalt() throws IOException{
            //generate Salt value
            // password, iv and salt should be transferred to the other end
            // in a secure manner
            // salt is used for encoding
            // writing it to a file
            // salt should be transferred to the recipient securely
            // for decryption
    byte[] salt = new byte[8];
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    secureRandom.nextBytes(salt);
            FileOutputStream saltOutFile = new FileOutputStream("C:\\KryptZIP\\salt.enc" , true);
            saltOutFile.write(salt);
        saltOutFile.close();
            return salt;


}
```

as mentioned in comment: this is my read salt value

```
    public static byte[] readSalt() throws IOException{
    // reading the salt
            // user should have secure mechanism to transfer the
            // salt, iv and password to the recipient
            FileInputStream saltFis = new FileInputStream("C:\\KryptZIP\\salt.enc");
            byte[] salt = new byte[8];
            saltFis.read(salt);
            saltFis.close();
            return salt;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with [`new FileOutputStream(filename, true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream-java.lang.String-boolean-)?

Comment: I don't see any problem. It is appending 8 bytes of data to the salt file every time I run your code.

Comment: Let say i use this :
FileOutputStream saltOutFile = new FileOutputStream("C:\\KryptZIP\\salt.enc",true);

will this add the next salt onto the salt file? cause i wonder will it appear as next line

Comment: Speaking about a "line" makes only sense in _character-based_ scenarios (for example when using a [`Reader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html)). You are using an [`OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) which is completely _byte-based_. There is no concept like a "line" in such streams. Additionally, why don't you simply try it out?

Comment: You are writing _bytes_ into a file. You cannot expect to read it as _text_.

Comment: i will upload my reading salt function also.

Comment: will adding a delimited such as ";" work?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the constructor of `FileOutputStream` with 2 arguments. The second argument is a boolean flag indicating whether you want to *append* (`true`) to the file or write *from the beginning* (`false`).

Change your code to:

```
 FileOutputStream saltOutFile = new FileOutputStream("C:\\KryptZIP\\salt.enc", true);
```

Comment: nice solution bro. but any idea how to i make the next salt on the next line instead of at the end of the line?

Comment: You can always write a newline character (`saltOutFile.write('\n');`)at the end of the salt. But since this is binary data, why would you want that? You can't read it with a text editor in any case.

Comment: the reason is that i am using it for encryption and currently i am unable to read the correct salt for the correct encrpytion.
example i encrypt A. generate salt A. store into salt file
when i encrypt B. Generate salt B .. store B into file. 
i unable to identify which salt is for which..so was plannig to make it to different line

Answer (score 1):

Use the Apache [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeByteArrayToFile(java.io.File,%20byte[],%20boolean)). Use the methdod

```
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(java.io.File file,bytes[] content,boolean append)
```

Comment: Why using a whole library, if a simple [`new FileOutputStream(filename, true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream-java.lang.String-boolean-) will do?

Comment: as the library handle to close the resources